# Can I apply the CoH: Going Rogue retail code after the Freedom patch and still get the benefits?

Tags: city-of-heroes

Can I apply a retail code to an account that already has a retail code applied? I only applied this code from COH GR AFTER Freedom was launched. Do I still get the same benefits as a VIP, the costume pieces, powersets and reward tokens?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply multiple retail codes to City of Heroes accounts that already have retail codes on them, within some limitations.  (For example, I do not think you can apply multiple copies of the same type of retail box on a single account, so if you have already applied Going Rogue to your account, you likely cannot add a second Going Rogue code but may be able to add an Architect Edition code.)

To answer your question specific to applying Going Rogue after Freedom, I found [this City of Heroes forum post](http://boards.cityofheroes.com/showpost.php?p=3907552&postcount=14) that describes what you get in great detail.  But to summarize here, you would get:

- 30 days of VIP access (this includes your 400 Paragon Points for being a VIP member for a month, as well as corresponding Reward Tokens)
- All the Going Rogue costume pieces and emotes (ex. Resistance and Praetorian Clockwork pieces)
- All the Going Rogue powersets (Dual Pistols, Demon Summoning, Electric Control Kinetic Melee)
- Access to the alignment system
- Access to Praetoria